# Algorithm for reducing Unnecessary Movement?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, zooming

- Let's say I have a rectangle with width 100 and height 50.
- Over the course of a set time, there will be a point in the rectangle moving around, lets say every millisecond.
- Between every millisecond, the point position might not change, change by a little, or change by a large amount.
- Now let say I want to zoom in 2x on the original rectangle so only 50 by 25 of the rectangle is visible (1/4 the size of the original) at one time.
- I want to keep the point visible at all times when zooming in, so the rectangle of 50 by 25 will be moving around to keep the point visible.
- My question involves keeping the cursor visible at all times within the smaller rectangle.
- A naive implementation would be to make the smaller rectangle's center be the position of the point at every millisecond so it is constantly visible. However, this would not be visually optimal since for example, if the point moves to the right one pixel, there shouldn't really be a need to move since the cursor will still be visible.
- **I was wondering if there were any algorithms/resources that could help find out the ideal center of the small rectangle at every millisecond to minimize unnecessary movement and make it as smooth as possible. Also, all the locations of the point at every millisecond will be available beforehand. Any suggestions/feedback are appreciated.**

Comment: A simple, first thing to try might be the moving average. Average the last N observed positions (i.e. calculate the moving average) and center the rectangle there.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you zoom in, you break your rectangle into four pieces. Check to see in which rectangle your cursor is and watch only that rectangle. If the cursor changes rectangle, move to that one. Given you know the position of the cursor, and with the help of mod and div you can find which small rectangle you need to see.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that the movement will not be smooth at all. Also, if for example, there are two neighboring points but each on different quadrants, switching between them will be a drastic change.

Comment: What to you define as smoothness? You could get the largest possible movement and move towards the cursor as a fraction of that.

Comment: Smooth as in, imagine as if the small rectangle was moved around on top of the large rectangle, with as few moves as necessary, but enough so it doesn't look like a jump. I want it to look more like a panning. Could you explain the 2nd part?

Comment: Given you don't know how far the rectangle will go, this cannot be very smooth. Let's say you can jump up to 20 away. Now let's assume your cursor is somewhere up right. If it moves a little down (let's say 3), then you move your window 1 down. If it moves 10 down, you move your window 10 down. That way, it is kind smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I would go at it like this:

- Check if the point is still visible, which means inside of the current view
- If it is, you're done.
- If it's not, you want to move the viewport as little as possible, which means calculating the distance between the closest side of the viewport and the point.

To do that, you need the coordinates of the four vertices of the viewport and the coordinates of the point. Since you have two coordinates, you can treat the sides of the viewport as lines equations and apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) to determine which is the closest one.

After you know which side to "move", you can take, for instance, the point as the middle one for the "moving" side and rebuild the viewport around that (maybe giving it some marging to ensure it is visible).